# When using Reverse Selector Pattern on styled-components props doesn`t work?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

When referring to parent components and using props the props doesn't work as expected.
I edited the example code in the docs of the link below to have 3 Link components with an Icon component inside that changes its color when hovering the parent (Link). It should change to red if Icon has a red prop or yellow if it hasn't, but all 3 Icons always change to the same color.

And they also behavior in a strange way, if none of the Icons have a red prop or if the first one have a red prop they all change to yellow on hover but if the first one doesn't have a red prop and at least one of the other Icon has they all change to red on hover.

That last part probably wasn't clear but you can test it pasting the code below over the code in the [docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) and adding or removing the red prop on the Icons and seeing the results.

I want to understand why it is behaving that way and if it is my logic or the way I am implementing that is wrong.

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components

```
const Link = styled.a`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: papayawhip;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

const Icon = styled.svg`
  flex: none;
  transition: fill 0.25s;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;

  ${Link}:hover & {
    fill: ${props => props.red ? "red" : "yellow"};
  }
`;

const Label = styled.span`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.2;

  &::before {
    content: '◀';
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
`;

render(
<div>
  <Link href="#">
    <Icon viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M10 15h8c1 0 2-1 2-2V3c0-1-1-2-2-2H2C1 1 0 2 0 3v10c0 1 1 2 2 2h4v4l4-4zM5 7h2v2H5V7zm4 0h2v2H9V7zm4 0h2v2h-2V7z"/>
    </Icon>
    <Label>Hovering my parent changes my style!</Label>
  </Link>
  <Link href="#">
    <Icon red viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M10 15h8c1 0 2-1 2-2V3c0-1-1-2-2-2H2C1 1 0 2 0 3v10c0 1 1 2 2 2h4v4l4-4zM5 7h2v2H5V7zm4 0h2v2H9V7zm4 0h2v2h-2V7z"/>
    </Icon>
    <Label>Hovering my parent changes my style!</Label>
  </Link>
  <Link href="#">
    <Icon red viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M10 15h8c1 0 2-1 2-2V3c0-1-1-2-2-2H2C1 1 0 2 0 3v10c0 1 1 2 2 2h4v4l4-4zM5 7h2v2H5V7zm4 0h2v2H9V7zm4 0h2v2h-2V7z"/>
    </Icon>
    <Label>Hovering my parent changes my style!</Label>
  </Link>
</div>
);
```